# Dagger subcomponent with contributor

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm having trouble injecting a fragment that I contribute via `@ContributesAndroidInjector`.

I'm trying to build a hierarchy within modules (features). Basically, what I have is:

- Core
- App
- Feature

My `AppComponent` depends on `CoreComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [CoreModule::class])
interface CoreComponent {

    fun getApp(): Application

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance app: Application): CoreComponent
    }
}
```

And initialize as:

```
@AppScope
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        ActivityContributor::class,
        AppModule::class],
    dependencies = [CoreComponent::class]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(component: CoreComponent): AppComponent
    }
}
```

This part is pretty much straightforward. AppComponent has `ActivityContributor` which only has one `@ContributesAndroidInjector`, which is `MainActivity`.

Now, problem starts when I want to add an encapsulated feature subcomponent. Assume I have two fragments `FragmentOne` and `FragmentTwo` in my feature, with some common dependencies as well as their own.

What I want to have is a `FeatureSubcomponent` which has `FeatureModule` and `FeatureContributor`:

```
@FeatureScope
@Subcomponent(
    modules = [FeatureContributor::class,
        FeatureModule::class
    ]
)
abstract class FeatureSubcomponent {

    @Subcomponent.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(): FeatureSubcomponent
    }
}
```

While `FeatureModule` has dependencies common for both fragments, `FeatureContributor` is contributing `FragmentOne` and `FragmentTwo` with their own modules:

```
@Module
abstract class FeatureContributor {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FeatureOneModule::class])
    abstract fun featureOneFragment(): FeatureOneFragment

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FeatureTwoModule::class])
    abstract fun featureTwoFragment(): FeatureTwoFragment
}
```

And of course, I add `FeatureSubcomponent` as a subcomponent to `AppModule`:

```
@Module(subcomponents = [FeatureSubcomponent::class])
```

And if you scroll up, you'll see `AppModule` is included in modules of `AppComponent`.

Problem is, while it's compiling and running, it crashes once it reaches to any feature fragments due to `No injector factory bound for` error.

Roughly summarising my structure:

- CoreComponent
- AppComponent

  - FeatureComponent (SUB)

    - FeatureOneComponent (SUB)
    - FeatureTwoComponent (SUB)

Anyone has ideas about why or how it should be instead or am I missing something ?

**Edit**

Here's the diagram I prepared to make it easier to understand hierarchy

[image: Dagger hierarchy diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dagger android does injection by finding the closest injector in the current scope. For Fragment, it is the containing Activity and for Activity it is the Application instance.

When you call `AndriodInject.inject(this)` in the Fragment it is goes up the hierarchy to find injector and then injects the Fragment.

Have you extended `DaggerAppCompatActivity`/implemented the `HasFragmentInjector`?

Another thing I see is, why create subcomponent again when `@ContributesAndroidInjector` already creates a sub component internally for you?

`@ContributesAndroidInjector.modules` is a way for talking to the generated subcomponent. So the **relationship between Activity and FeatureFragment must be established in the subcomponent that the @ContributesAndroidInjector will be generating.**

Right now your hierarchy is like this since you have deliberately specified `FeatureSubComponent` to be subcomponent of the `AppComponent`

```
App -> FeatureSubComponent -> [A, B] (generated)
      \
       \---> MainActivitySubcomponent (generated by contributesAndroidInjector).
```

What you actually need is:

```
App -> MainActivitySubComponent (generated) -> [Feature A , Feature B] (generated)
```

To do this

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FeatureContributor::class])
abstact fun mainActivity() : MainActivity
```

Feature contributor can have `@ContributesAndroidInjectors` inside. When Dagger compiler sees that `FeatureContributor` has `@ContributesAndroidInjectors`, it makes the subcomponent generated by those to be the subcomponent of the activity since it is the parent.

Which basically means `Activity -> Fragment` hierarchy.